# Python/Docker : FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: python, docker

I am using a Python code to open a text file and write some information and close it. When I run this code on Jupyter notebook it runs perfectly but when I run this as a part of Docker container it gives the following error.

Current directory is C:/app where I have stored Dockerfile, testfile.txt and Hello1.py. In addition I have gone to Virtual Machine and have added C: as shared folder.

Python File

```
  file = open("C:/Python/testfile.txt","w")
  file.write("Hello World")
  file.write("This is our new text file")
  file.close()
```

Docker File

```
 FROM python:latest
 WORKDIR /data
 COPY testfile.txt /data
 COPY Hello1.py /data
 CMD ["python","Hello1.py"]
```

Error Recieved

```
 $ docker run sid1980
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "Hello1.py", line 7, in <module>
 file = open("C:/Python/testfile.txt","w")
 FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Python/testfile.txt'
```

Comment: You say the directory is named `app` but in the code it is named `Python`

Comment: I am talking about the present working directory from where I am building Docker image.

Answer (score 3):

I was having a very similar error and just fixed it, so I hope this answer helps.

So, what happens is when you do `docker run IMAGE`, and your code inside the image accesses a file, it is relative to **the root of the image**.

So if your actual fd looks like this:

```
Python
 testfile.txt
```

And the fd in your image looks like this:

```
directory
 randomfile.txt
```

Then, you are going to get an error, because there is no `Python` directory, much less a `testfile.txt`, inside the image.

So, what you can do, at least in Mac, is that you can use the `--volume` flag when doing `docker run` to specify where you want to local file to appear in the docker image. For example, you can do something like `docker run --name IMAGENAME --volume /Python:/usr/directory/Python` to have your Python folder be staged at `/usr/directory/Python` inside the image. Then, you can use the "staged" folder in your code by writing in your code something like

`file = open("C:/usr/Python/testfile.txt","w")`

(Not sure exactly what the root of the image is considered on Windows, so use `pwd` to confirm)

Of course, change the argument for where you want the folder/file to appear in the image to your needs. This link was pretty helpful when I was solving this problem: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#choose-the--v-or---mount-flag.

P.S. If you want to see what the file directory of your image looks like, you can do `docker exec IMAGENAME bash` after `docker run`ning it.

Answer (score 2):

Your python program cannot access `C:/` of the host machine. You need to change the file path to reference the `testfile.txt` that exists *within the container*.

```
file = open("/data/testfile.txt","w")
```

Also note that this will not modify the `testfile.txt` that exists on the host. It will write to the file that is inside the container.

Comment: Hello New Contributor I changed my python code to reflect your suggestion and rebuilt the image with name sid1980. When I use the command                                                
 $ docker run -v //c/Sid:/data sid1980    and it still gives the error python: can't open file 'EIA.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Not sure you can do that mount with `v //c/Sid:/data`. What I would do is getting inside the folder I'm trying to mount with the powershell and enter `pwd`, copy the output as the first part of the mount. I would even do it all at once like `-v $(pwd):/data`.